# Value in Pivot Table in excel linked to another fomula

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I want the value of **Amount - Vlookup** column to be 0. Only the first cell of the column works by the formula but when I drag the first cell of the column, the value the second and third value are not automatically getting the correct answer.

Formula for the first cell of the column: =GETPIVOTDATA("Amount ",$I$12,"Invoice/Receipt#",2031000477)+L22

Formula for the second cell of the column: =GETPIVOTDATA("Amount ",$I$12,"Invoice/Receipt#",2031000477)+L23

Formula for the third cell of the column: =GETPIVOTDATA("Amount ",$I$12,"Invoice/Receipt#",2031000477)+L24

[image]

Comment: I would suggest including row/columns in your table image next time to make it easier for answers to reference cells in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula references a specific row in the pivot table.

`=GETPIVOTDATA("Amount ",$I$12,"Invoice/Receipt#",2031000477)` is looking up the row with invoice number `2031000477`. When you copy this formula down, it continues to use that hard coded value and look up that specific row, returning the same result.

The way to change this behaviour is to change the formula to reference the value in the pivot table that you are using as the lookup.

Using the example table you gave, and assuming your pivot table starts top-left at cell `$I$12` as given, and you have written your formula into cell `L14`, then you should change your formula to read:

`=GETPIVOTDATA("Amount ",$I$12,"Invoice/Receipt#",I14)`

and then copy this formula down the subsequent rows.